# Rearrange words in a given sentence in python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm very new to python.

I get a serial data in COM port in fixed format as a string like this:

```
"21-12-2015 10:12:05 005 100 10.5 P"
```

The format is 'date time id count data data'

Here i don't require count and first data, instead i want to add one more data and send this again through another COM port.

I want to rearrange this and give output as

```
21-12-2015 10:12:05
    SI.NO: 1451
   Result: 10.5 P
```

My attempt:

```
ip = '21-12-2015_10:12:05_005_100_10.5 P'

dt = ip[0]+ip[1]+ip[3]+.....   #save date as dt
tm = ip[9]+ip[10]+ip[11]+....  etc
```

and at the end

```
Result = dt + tm +"\n" + "        "+ "SI.NO"+.......
```

Please suggest some good concept to do this in python 2.7.11
If you can mention some ideas i will search for the code.

Thank you

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. It helps to do two things when asking questions here: be specific about what you're trying to do, and show what efforts you've already taken to solve the problem. Example: it seems like your data is formatted such that the first step would be to split it up by the underscores; have you tried to look up how to do this?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting, I have changed it.

Comment: Where is `SI.NO: 1451` coming from? Or is this always the same?

Comment: That data I want to add to the input stream, and create a new stream. Its like a counter.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split use a space as the delimiter string then assign ``(date, time, a, b, c, d)=ip.split(" ")``

Comment: @Dannysam Nicely done.

Comment: @Vorsprung You saved my day! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split up your string on whitespace into fields with [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and build a new string using Python's [string formatting syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
ip = "21-12-2015 10:12:05 005 100 10.5 P"
fields = ip.split()
s = '{date} {time}\n    SI.NO: {sino}\n   Result: {x} {y}'.format(
        date=fields[0],
        time=fields[1],
        sino=1451,        # Provide your own counter here
        x=fields[4],
        y=fields[5])
print s

21-12-2015 10:12:05
    SI.NO: 1451
   Result: 10.5 P
```

It isn't clear from your question whether your fields are separated by spaces or underscores. In the latter case, use `fields = ip.split('_')`.